# wifi is connected in ubuntu but internet is not working

Tags: wireless, internet

I have installed ubuntu recently, wifi is connected to ubuntu but internet is not working.

Where as the same wifi is connected in window laptop, and internet is working in windows.

Please help me out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Network Manager>

Click 'Edit'

Edit the wireless connection>

Click the IPv6 tab>

Set IPv6 to ignore>

click OK>

Reboot.

Comment: i tried it, still not working