# Wifi is working but no internet

Tags: 16.04, wireless, connection

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a MSI GE60. Connected to the Wifi, got an IP address but no internet.
I applied the following post [wifi is connected in ubuntu but internet is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880771/wifi-is-connected-in-ubuntu-but-internet-is-not-working) without success.
Any idea?
Thanks
Regards

Comment: Are you able to ping 8.8.4.4?

Comment: Yes. I also tried to change Firefox Proxy settings, but no results.

Comment: Looks like just your DNS settings are wrong.

Comment: Followed the answer in https://superuser.com/questions/920029/dns-issue-in-ubuntu-14-04. It works now. Thanks @davidbaumann for your help!