# Wifi is connected but suddenly not working at all on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Lenovo Thinkpad more than a year ago, it seems to be working, having issues from time to time though. For example, I did not manage to " install Update" from "software and updates", but as I manage to work, did not bother too much till today. So now, for some reason, wlan is connected, showing great signal strength, but I am not able to reach internet (not able to surf anything). To post this bug-report, I tried to connect to Ethernet, however, to my biggest surprise, that too connected but could not make me to reach internet (copying this stuff via USB from affected laptop to working laptop for posting this bug).

I already surfed internet, tried few things, did not work. This page ([wifi is connected in ubuntu but internet is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880771/wifi-is-connected-in-ubuntu-but-internet-is-not-working)) seem to mention the exact problem as mine, however did not help either.

```
pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"

pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5914 (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5917 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d12 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
03:00.0 Wireless controller [0d40]: Intel Corporation Device 7360 (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a808
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 15d3 (rev 02)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 15d3 (rev 02)
06:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 15d3 (rev 02)
06:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 15d3 (rev 02)
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 15d3 (rev 02)
07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 15d2 (rev 02)
3b:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 15d4 (rev 02)

pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 78
       serial: b4:6b:fc:f5:d8:f9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.19.0-041900rc4-lowlatency firmware=36.e91976c0.0 ip=192.168.178.42 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:158 memory:ee300000-ee301fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: 8c:16:45:ad:03:a5
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:155 memory:ee400000-ee41ffff
```

As my work is completely stuck, I would appreciate some way around to make it working, quite disappointed with this sudden surprise.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

it was dns issue, resolved!!!!